# Swift - load image from URL

Tags: swift2, xcode7, imageurl

I'm creating a medicine database as practice and I would like to load image of pills from URLs.

Here is part of my code and it says

Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'

How am I supposed to fix it ?
Thank you!

```
func img_URL(urlString:String)
    {

        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.pillsImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
        })

    }
```

Comment: @LeoDabus It isn't, you know (a duplicate of that).

Answer (score 1):

Do what the error message tells you! Change

```
completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

to

```
completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?,data: NSData?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Even better, abandon NSURLConnection. It is replaced by NSURLSession. The call you are making is *deprecated* and will be *removed* in a future system update (possibly as soon as this June).

Answer (score 1):

```
completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

will solve your issue

Comment: Remarkably similar to my answer.

Comment: LOL - did not see your answer the view of the page I had

Comment: I know! happens to me all the time too

Comment: I pasted his code into a playground, fixed it and then added my answer.  You responded in the interim.  O well ...

Comment: I formatted your answer and upvoted it. :)

Comment: By the way, the docs also would be enough: not need for the playground. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Comment: yeah I up voted you too